# Configure the mod_proxy65 of ejabberd to be invalid from part virtual host

Tags: ejabberd

I`m using jeabberd 15.10 to Configure the mod_proxy65, for that(part info):

```
hosts: 
  - "test.server1"
  - "test.server2"
  - "pre.hooca.com.cn"    
shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000    
access:
  proxy_shaper:
    admin: none
    all: fast    
auth_method: internal
odbc_pool_size: 20
odbc_keepalive_interval: 30

modules:
  ........
  mod_proxy65:
    name: "SOCKS5 Bytestreams"
    ip: "192.168.5.107"
    port: 7777
    access: all
    shaper: proxy_shaper                        
host_config:
  "pre.hooca.com.cn":
    auth_method: odbc
    odbc_type: mysql
    ...        
    modules:
     ....
      mod_proxy65:
        name: "SOCKS5 Bytestreams"
        ip: "192.168.5.107"
        port: 7777
        access: all
        shaper: proxy_shaper
```

I find that: the VM(test.server1 and test.server2) seems to use the shaper( fast: 50000), the VM(pre.hooca.com.cn) seems to use the shaper( fast: 1000), i don`t know the reson, who can help me,thanks!!!

Comment: the VM(pre.hooca.com.cn) seems to use the shaper 1000 ,but i hope to use shaper 50000.

Answer (score 0):

Now i have resolved it. copy all data from common module to host_config/module and modify diff data on host_config/module.